# O hover dos botões do site está errado?

Tags: bug, status-pronto, design, interface-usuário

Tenho quase certeza de que a cor laranja está incorreta e foi *herdada* do site principal. Acho que está errado porque laranja é uma cor muito forte e só hoje cheguei a prestar atenção nisso.

Isso está certo?

[image: Botão em seu estado normal] [image: Botão em hover]

<sup>Botão em seu estado normal; botão em hover.</sup>

Comment: Volta e meia a empresa faz uma [baguncinha](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kexc1q5LNHQ) no layout

Comment: Eu como uso um style dark nem dei conta.

Comment: Já agora foi herdado de onde? Não vejo mais nenhum botão laranja nem no SOen...

Comment: @JorgeB. anteontem inclusive trocaram acidentalmente a cor do "score novo", é pra ser verde, mas estava azul, ai mais tarde corrigiram.

Comment: Isso [também foi reportado no meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340412/401803), mas nenhuma resposta até agora...

Comment: @hkotsubo logo o Nicolas aparece dizendo que não sabe de nada.

Comment: Você fala do meta ou do principal mesmo? Ou fala do SOen? No principal eu acho que foi feito de propósito. Se está reclamando de ter copiado do SOen, por que não deveria ter aqui?

Comment: Pelo jeito já foi corrigido: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340476/401803

Comment: Sim, já está OK. =)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento quem? :P